# (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)j though there is no cron job is scheduled

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron, ubuntu-16.04, syslog, amazon-cloudwatch

In my /var/log/syslog file I can see the above log is entered in every minute. Though I have checked my crontab and found nothing configured there to run.

My /var/log/syslog is as follows:
[image]

And the crontab is as follows:

[image]

Here I should mention that my system is an AWS-EC2 instance which is running on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text that can be copied and pasted, and if you have to use a screenshot then cut off irrelevant parts, such as your desktop. All this makes it harder to get information out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are only listing your personal crontab. Run `ls -lR /etc/cron*` to see files that contain system cronjobs.

On Ubuntu this looks like this:

```
$ ls -lR /etc/cron*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 722 Apr  5  2016 /etc/crontab

/etc/cron.d:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 589 Jul 16  2014 mdadm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 712 Jan 18  2018 php

/etc/cron.daily:
total 44
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  539 Apr  5  2016 apache2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  376 Mar 31  2016 apport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1478 Jul  9  2018 apt-compat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1176 Nov  2  2017 dpkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2211 Apr 13  2014 locate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  372 May  6  2015 logrotate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  539 Jul 16  2014 mdadm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  249 Nov 12  2015 passwd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  383 Nov  8 19:09 samba
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  246 Mar 21  2018 ubuntu-advantage-tools
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  214 May 24  2016 update-notifier-common

/etc/cron.weekly:
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 211 May 24  2016 update-notifier-common
```

All these files contain various jobs that are configured by default.

To get rid of that syslog messages, install and configure an MTA (mail transfer agent).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But as I said the log is generating in every minute not in weekly, daily or hourly. That's why I didn't share the other crontabs. Another thing is the issue is happening recently. The other crontabs is as it was before. That's why I think the issue is not creating by the other crontabse.

Comment: Your screenshot does not show the user the crontab belongs to. It's always useful to provide the command you used to get a result. The files in `/etc/cron.d` can contain jobs that are run every minute. Your question does not show that you already checked that.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I found the cron command which is running in every minute by the following command: `crontab -l`. I can see the following command is running in every minute: `*/1 * * * * ~/.aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --aws-credential-file="/home/subroot/.aws-scripts-mon/credentials.conf" --mem-util --mem-used --disk-space-util --disk-path=/ --from-cron`. It says the aws credential files is at `/home/subroot/` folder but I checked and found no `/home/subroot/' folder in the instance! Any clue? Thanks